# Instagram Manage Applications - Randomly Removing Apps

Tags: facebook, rest, oauth-2.0, instagram, instagram-api

We've been trying to diagnose issues with some of our users who use our application for Instagram. We've been noticing that some access tokens have been return a 400 error for some users (Access Token Invalid).

We were able to get in touch with a few of these users, and asked them to check their "Manage Applications" section on their Instagram account through the Instagram website.

To ours, and their suprise - our application was no longer on the list, and none of these users (Over 20 asked and helping us diagnose) said they revoked access.

What's going on here? We have nearly 3,000 users using our service, but it seem 30 to 50 of these total users are having our application randomly removed from their enabled applications without them doing so.

Comment: Instagram revokes access to app if they detect spam from a user account, like auto liking or auto follow

Comment: I can confirm what krisrak said.